# Using Flutter ChangeNotifierProvider for authentication

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, dart, provider

I am using ChangeNotifierProvider to handle app state for my flutter app.

**My main.dart file**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/services/auth.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthService>(
        create: (context) => AuthService(), // initializes auth.dart file here
        child: MaterialApp(
          initialRoute: '/',
          onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: '...',
          home: WelcomeScreen(),
        ));
  }
}
```

I am trying to change the value of the **uid** field here in **auth.dart**

**auth.dart file**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthService with ChangeNotifier {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  String uid = ""; //initial value of uid

  UserM _userFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
    return user != null ? UserM(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  Stream<UserM> get user {
    return null;
  }

  Future signInWithEmail(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      User user = result.user;
      uid = user.uid; //trying to change uid here
      print('user id: $uid'); //new value is printed here
      notifyListeners();
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

uid changes but then when i try to get the new value in another file, i still get the old value which is the empty string declared on top.
This is how i am trying to access it

```
final auth = Provider.of<AuthService>(context, listen: true).uid;
print(auth);
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: Why don't you just access your `uid` through your class model which is  `UserM` which you already save the result there

Comment: i  wish to use it in the other screens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get why there is a need to use `Provider` to get the uid of a user in `Firebase`. You can get the `uid` synchronously by doing `currentUser.uid`.
Here is an example:

```
print(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid);
```

Comment: Okay. I get this but then I need to know why this ain't working

Comment: you've used provider in a wrong way. You have to call notifyListners() after you set the value. Take a look at this to have a more in depth understanding about provider: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_m5csmrf7I